# Can I pass a variable from a UIWebView back to my app using Javascript (or any web technology)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with a form on it.  I would like to get the response from the form sent back to my application so that it can respond accordingly.  Is there anyway to do this with javascript or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

`NSString *formValue1 = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.forms[0].elements[0]"];`

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense. I also found a similar answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585193/help-using-javascript-code-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: But this is something your native Objective-C method will call. How can UIWebview pass value to Objective-C or rather how can webpage invoke Objective-C method ?