# Javascript interface with iPhone webview

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am converting coding from Android to iPhone, below is the code listen to "jb" from javascript in Android webview.  How can I implement the code in iPhone?

```
  webView.loadUrl(url); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient ());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptBridge(), "jb");


final class JavascriptBridge
    {
        public void callback(String param){

            //Generate the returnValue from the bridge
            /*
            String toastValue = param
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AppHelp.this, toastValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            */
            Log.i(TAG, param);
            if (param.equals("close")) {
                AppHelp.this.finish();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve in iOS? Alternative to JavascriptInterface  in iOS?

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading this right, you want to convert this Android WebView code to iPhone.
First, you create a UIWebView:

```
UIWebView* web = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] initWithURL:@"google.com"];
```

Second, you will want evaluate some JavaScript using the following method:

```
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE"];
```

To respond to a JavaScript function will be a little bit more difficult.  I don't believe there is an iOS alternative to JavascriptBridge.  You will want to see this question for further reference:
[Can I pass a variable from a UIWebView back to my app using Javascript (or any web technology)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620972/can-i-pass-a-variable-from-a-uiwebview-back-to-my-app-using-javascript-or-any-we)